# How to remove array values from an object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, for-in-loop

```
var obj = {
a: [1, 3, 4],
b: 2,
c: ['hi', 'there']
   }
   removeArrayValues(obj);
   console.log(obj); // --> { b: 2 }
```

Here is my code:

```
function removeArrayValues(obj) {
 for (var key in obj){
 if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) delete obj[key]
 //return obj[key] -> {b: 2, c: ["hi", "there"]}
 }
 return obj[key]
}
```

Why does it return only `obj["a"]` and `obj["c"]` when I return it inside the `for/in loop` and not `obj["k"]`.  I figured the problem out right before I was about to post this but I run into this issue a lot with both arrays and objects and could use an explanation of what is going on here.

Comment: It's not clear what you didn't understand. The if returns "true", "false" and "true".

Comment: *"and not obj["k"]"* - Where does the `"k"` you're asking about come from? If you have a `return` statement *inside* the loop as per the line that you've commented out, then that exits the function immediately without completing the loop. Note that the `return` value from your function will be `undefined`, because `obj[key]` is undefined after the loop removes the last item.

Comment: What I can see is that you have successfully removed all object keys that contain the value of array.. What's the question again?

Answer (score 2):

First, let's see your object. It has 3 key/value pairs:

```
var obj = {
    a: [1, 3, 4],//the value here is an array
    b: 2,//the value here is not an array
    c: ['hi', 'there']//the value here is an array
};
```

For each key in that object, your `removeArrayValues` function will delete any of them which has an array as value:

```
if (Array.isArray(obj[key]))
```

That condition will return "true" if the value is an array. You can check this in this demo: the `console.log` inside the `for` loop will log "true", "false" and "true":

```js
var obj = {
a: [1, 3, 4],
b: 2,
c: ['hi', 'there']
   }
   removeArrayValues(obj);

function removeArrayValues(obj) {
 for (var key in obj){
 console.log(Array.isArray(obj[key]))
 if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) delete obj[key]
 //return obj[key] -> {b: 2, c: ["hi", "there"]}
 }
 return obj[key]
}
```

So, the first key will be removed ("true"), the second one will not ("false"), and the third one will be removed ("true").